# iOS timer outside application

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to make my first app, its going really well. I know quite a few programming languages, however I've run into a problem.

I am trying to limit the user to do, at most, one action every hour. I've been trying to make a timer. I've also dabbled in some server side code to help me, however I can't seem to make it work. I was wondering if anyone had any answers that could help me?

Comment: Im going to go with a better server side option, Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve it through iPhone locally.

- One can change the clock time on device and solution with stored time
  stamp will not work.
- Timers are not running in back ground. So that    solution will not
  work.

To achieve it, you will have to write server side business.
Before performing any operation, check from server side, if an hour has been passed or not.
Whenever there will be a request to server, server will update last operation time(if hour has been passed) for that particular user. This time will be set by server and not dependent on client's local time.

Comment: Looks like im going to have to rewrite my app so it works with SQL then
Thanks for the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach would be the following:
1. Keep the last time of user action is some file or a database (or in NSUserDefaults)
2. Upon letting the user perform an action check the stored timestamp to see if 1 hour has passed since last invocation.

Additionally, it might be neccessary to check this against a server-side (to avoid removing and re-installing the application reset the stored timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@interface YourClass
@property (assign, nonatomic) double lastActionTime;
@end

@implementation YourClass

- (BOOL)isActionAllowed
{
    double currentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    if (currentTime - 3600 > lastActionTime)
    {
        lastActionTime = currentTime;
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

You may save `lastActionTime` in `NSUserDefaults` to keep it even app is closed.

That solution assuming user do not change date or re-install app.

Answer (score 0):

Use **NSTimer** to disable the action  an hour.

`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` will help you to achieve this.

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:yourTimeinterval target:self selector:@selector(trigger) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```