# How can I allow users to use application only once per day?

Tags: iphone, ios, timing

I am a new programmer and have searched for this answer, but think I might not be using the right terminology.

What I am trying to do is allow the user to use my application, which is a game, only once in a 24 hour period. If they try to play the game earlier than the 24 hour period, I would like an alert that tells them to come back later. I have seen this done for other games that give you "credits", but can't seem to find the code.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you will find this out of the box. Do you want to implement some kind of energy feature? In any case, what you need to do to get started is to store the last time you user played, and compare the current time against this saved time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `NSDate` class to get the current date (`[NSDate date]`), and then save this value using the `NSUserDefaults` class. When the app is opened, retrieve the value and then compare the old date with the current date. If it has been a day, don't do anything. Otherwise, show an alert.

```
//setting the date
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"Date"];

//retrieve date
NSDate *date = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Date"];

//now compare the dates
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you, one thing I want to add in case anybody else wants to use this, once I had the two different dates, I used NSCalendar and NSDateComponents in order to figure out if the difference in dates was 24 hours or more, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the above re: persisting an NSDate.  If you're okay with the constraint being potentially violated on reinstall, then NSUserDefaults makes the most sense.

The other question you need to ask and answer is what you really mean by "run" once.  Does it mean launch once and run a lot, or becomeActive only once, or something else?  Say  user plays for a minute then gets a phone call (that's one didFinishLaunching and two didBecomeActive's) how do your enforce then?

What you might really need is a total play time that cannot exceed some value over the trailing 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Your app opens, you set the current date/time to when the game starts. Every time the app opens you check if you are 24 hours past the saved date/time and if you aren't then take them to another view or just show a message telling them to come back in *_*_ hours.

Look up saving NSDates to NSUserDefaults and how to compare NSDates and you should be able to pull this off relatively easily.

The problem with this approach is that they are able to delete the app and reinstall it which will reset your NSUserDefaults or any other local storage for that app. To get around that you would have to do user accounts on a server (probably what the other app you saw did) or at least send a unique ID for their device and handle it server side.

Comment: Another option is to save the date in the keychain. It will not be removed if the app is deleted. The keychain wasn't intended for this, but it works.

Comment: For that matter saving it to UIPasteboard but like you said it wasn't intended for that. Both of these options can work.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308313/ios-timer-outside-application/13308385#13308385) for similar question.

Anyway it does not block if user reinstall app or change date on a device manually. 
To achieve what you need it's best to keep & verify date when the user was actually running app through your external server. Perhaps you can use php on the server side and connect to it via NSURLConnection POST requests.